# Wireless Mouse only works with USB hub

Tags: macbook-pro, mouse

I have a Microsoft Wireless Mobile Mouse 4000 and a mid-2012 Macbook Pro (non-Retina). I normally have a lot of USB devices that I need to have plugged in so when I got my Macbook Pro I just continued to use my mouse plugged into my USB hub along with my other devices. But recently I was out somewhere and I just wanted to bring my mouse along with me and when I plugged the wireless dongle straight into the usb port it wouldn't recognize my mouse. I messed around with settings and tried to reinstall the drivers but that didn't work. When I got home I plugged it back into my USB hub and it worked. It's not really a big inconvenience but it's kind of strange and I'd like to fix it. Has anyone else experienced this or know of a solution?

Comment: It's hard to say without a bit more information. The first step would be to see what appears in **System Information** in the USB section. It gives you a tree view of all your USB devices, tell us what shows up with it plugged into the hub, and then just plugged directly to your MBP.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but my hunch is that this could be related to power consumption.  You have a powered USB hub, right?, so there's no problem there.  Maybe your (battery-powered) Mac doesn't have enough power on the USB bus for the transceiver.  Do you have any other USB devices plugged in, and if so, does the mouse work if you unplug them?

Comment: Ken: This shouldn't be a problem.  The receiver should be relatively low power, and he implies that he is using less USB devices than usual.  The MacBook Pro still meets any USB power standard, and Macs have actually supplied more power than other computers over USB for a while (that's why the Macs can charge iPads and some PCs can't).

Comment: @CanuckSkier I don't see a USB section under System Information. When I have the mouse plugged into the USB hub and the hub plugged into my MBP I can click on "Mouse" under "Hardware" and it will give settings that I can change but when I just plug the mouse into the USB port by itself the mouse doesn't respond and under "Mouse" it just says "No mouse found."

Comment: Just to be clear, you're using the System Information program in the Utilities folder (which is inside your Applications folder)? Mine looks [like this](http://i.imgur.com/y4jxH.png), USB is at the bottom of the Hardware section. I don't have a Mouse section.

Comment: @CanuckSkier Ah, ok. This is what I [see](http://i.imgur.com/FFNcW.png) when I just plug it straight into my MBP. This is what I [see](http://i.imgur.com/oG4XY.png) when I have it plugged into the USB hub.

Answer (score 1):

I have a brand new mid-2012 Macbook Pro i7 15", which I bought on 12-23-2012. I was using my bluetooth mouse but the secondary button wasn't working accurately in one of my applications, so I switched to my trusty Microsoft Wireless Mobile Mouse 4000. When I plugged the dongle into the USB 3.0 port, I got an error that said my laptop keyboard needed to be identified (?!). I couldn't get it 'identified' until I turned off my Bluetooth option. When I did that, both the mouse and the internal keyboard played nice.